String MACRO concatenation with string function
#include <stdio.h>
#define YY "Sample Text"
#define FINALDATA           "START TEXT (" func2(func1(142),YY) ") END TEXT"
// #define FINALDATA            func2(func1(142),YY) //this works fine

int func1(int data)
{
    return data;
}
char* func2(int val, char* data)
{
    return data;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Final Data is %s\n\n", FINALDATA);

    return 0;
}

in the above C/C++ program, I need to concatenate two strings with return value of the function. But below is the error
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:11:44: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘func2’
   11 | #define FINALDATA           "START TEXT (" func2(func1(142),YY) ") END TEXT"
      |                                            ^~~~~
main.cpp:25:36: note: in expansion of macro ‘FINALDATA’
   25 |     printf("Final Data is %s\n\n", FINALDATA);
      |                                    ^~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:25:11: note: to match this ‘(’
   25 |     printf("Final Data is %s\n\n", FINALDATA);
      |           ^

What might be wrong? isnt it possible to use MACRO this way to append the strings with a function call ?

Please don't spam multiple tags. Even through your code could be plain C, it's in a C++ source file, so you should only have the c++ tag. And while it's commonly used (misused really) there's no such thing as "C/C++".

As for the string concatenation, you can only concatenate actual literal strings. std::cout << "A" "B" "C"; is fine. char const* b = "B"; std::cout << "A" b "C"; is not fine.

String literal concatenation happens at compile-time only so you can't do it on char* variables. For run-time string concatenation in C++, consider std::string("hello") + "world" etc

Macros are expanded before compilation (it's a preprocessing step). "a" func2(1, "") "b" is a syntax error regardless of whether it's the result of a macro expansion or not.

You can group a series of string literals (and only string literals) and it will be treated as one bigger string literal. This happens at compile-time after pre-processing directives have been executed, after which "adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated" by the compiler.
No function calls or variables.
